# Can I turn this non-linear iterative function into a non-iterative function?

Tags: recursive-algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

My function looks like this:

```
function fn(startValue, iterations){
    var result = startValue;
    while(iterations--)
    {   // Loop the # of iterations
        result += 1 / (1 + result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If startValue = 0 and iterations = 3 then the resulting math would be...

```
startValue = 1 / (1 + startValue);
startValue = 1 / (1 + startValue);
startValue = 1 / (1 + startValue);
```

And we end up with startValue equaling 1.9

How can I get that same result without looping?

http://jsfiddle.net/LgJZP/

Comment: Note the "+=". This means that the iteration is "result = result + 1/(1+result)". THis is $(1+result+result^2)/result$.

Comment: That does not seem right. What you've written if started at `0` would result in a divide by zero. The part after `+=` above would add `1`, then `.5`, and then `.4`; it performs `result + 1 / (1 + result)` within each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the result. The numerator and denominator are Fibonacci numbers just starting at different places.